# Styling form elements in an Adobe Air app

Tags: html, css, air, forms

Built an Adobe Air app that has HTML forms in it. Apparently, Air has its own way of rendering form elements and disregards my CSS. Is there any elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is create a stylesheet that has the following property applied to the form elements that you want to override the (hideous) default AIR styles for:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```